# How focus to iframe afterShow with Fancybox3

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I can focus on the iframe with the command instance.focus () and thus press the key on the keyboard "right" after opening the iframe to navigate in it (to view this book) without first having to point to the ">" button or point somewhere inside the iframe.

However with this method, I lose the possibility to close the window of the iframe by the key "ESC", which I want to avoid.

Just put the instance.focus () command in comment to restore the operation of the "ESC" key.

How to get the focus of the iframe in another way without interfering with the key "ESC" ???

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" href="https://e.issuu.com/embed.html?embedType=script&u=actes_sud&d=l_onard_anatomiste_liseuse&p=">Léonard de Vinci anatomiste</a>

$(document).on("afterShow.fb",function(e,instance,slide){instance.focus()});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rpaul007/pen/vYYeVvR)

Answer (score 0):

fancybox listens on keydown event on the main page, but, these events do not bubble up from within iframed page. If you have control over the iframed page, you can add your own keydown listener there and close fancybox (using `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();`) on ESC.

Comment: I have not control over the iframed page ...

I have test this:

$(document).on("afterShow.fb",function(e,instance,slide){
    $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find("#ird3-button-next").focus();
});

with no success ...

Comment: ... as expected due to browser security. If you can not access iframe content due to CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), then you are out of luck to do anything with iframed page.

Comment: Thank you Janis for your intervention

Very likely that it is a problem of CORS ...

Waiting for other suggestions including that of the programmer of this application ...

Comment: I noticed just now that you are displaying issuu viewer and I can tell you that it is the same as, for example, with youtube videos - once iframed page gains focus, you are out of control and can not listen to keypress events.

Comment: OK Janis

So it's one or the other, that I can have the focus with instance.focus () but I lose the possibility of ESC or I put my instance.focus () in comment to keep my ESC;)

I think you're the fancybox developer?

If so, another question for you:

Is it possible with fancybox when opening a single image (not a gallery), that the mouse wheel can zoom in ???

Similarly, in a gallery of images, the mouse wheel is used to navigate through the images and it would be nice if a parameter could rather allow the zoom ...

Thanks ;)

Comment: That will be incorporated in the upcoming major version (but I can not tell when it will be ready to publish).